# Having problems with installation of microsoft sdk on win 7 home premium

Tags: windows-7, matlab, sdk, libsvm

I wanted to install libsvm in MATLAB r2012 on my laptop ( win 7 home premium system ) . Now on the site , libsvm asks to run `mex -setup` , when I run this command in matlab , it fails and asks to install windows SDK . Now I downloaded it and ran but it is not getting installed . I am unable to figure out what is going wrong . Could someone help me here

Comment: which windows sdk?

Comment: windows sdk 7.1